# refill a docx template with new data in the same document using docx4j

Tags: java, templates, docx4j

i am trying to fill a docx template with different data but i can not make any progress. I have tried two approaches. First using only java code and second one using content control binding. For the first approach i used this tutorial http://www.smartjava.org/content/create-complex-word-docx-documents-programatically-docx4j and for the second one this one https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/07c0b68512cbb3eef52ae51c3f597a7be4428232/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ContentControlBindingExtensions.java . The problem is I do not know how to reuse the same template and just fill it with other datasets? Should I use xsl in order to make the logic?
The picture below illustrates my goal, where first and second table are meant to be in the same document.

[image: Refill same template]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you do the binding, you create a new instance docx.

If you want the contents of multiple instance documents concatenated in a single docx, you'll have to do that as a separate step.

If the contents is simple text & tables, you can just copy the contents list.

More likely, it contains relationship references etc, in which case you need to handle those.